# My 'java' instruction point to JRE address, how can I change it back?

Tags: java, shell, java-8, environment-variables

```
C:\Users\Alex>java
Error: missing `server' JVM at `D:\config\java\bin\server\jvm.dll'.
Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.
```

I just executed jdk-8u301-windows-x64.exe, and installed both jdk/javaSE. When i tried to use 'java' instruction in win shell, such a message was found.

My jdk address is  D:\config\jdk, and D:\config\java is for javaSE.

Also my env variable setting is

```
JAVA_HOME: D:\config\jdk
```

Why 'java' instruction point to my java SE address ? And how can I change it back?
——————————————————————————————————————

I uninstalled both folders, and then reinshalled them. The program in java folder now have ../server/ and the instruction can run successfully. Seems it was missed in last installation. What's more, I read the install steps and found the folder I believed that was Java SE is actually jre.

However, I still feel puzzled about why java instruction search file in jre folder but not the folder I wrote in JAVA_HOME...

——————————————————————————————————————

I used 'where java' instruction before I asked this question. All the results are as same as I use it just now:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
D:\config\jdk\bin\java.exe
D:\config\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe
```

I did completely consistent steps with what I studied in my college period: set JAVA_HOME, CLASS_PATH and finally

```
path: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;
```

And yep, I know the second folder is jre after I read the steps: it's inshalled by the execute file. Strangely the 'java' instruction search file in it but not in D:\config\jdk\jre\bin\ .

Comment: It seems like what you write is not what you mean. The term “JavaSE” stands for “Java Standard Edition” and the JDK *is* JavaSE. Perhaps, you mean JRE, but since the JDK includes a JRE, there is no reason to install a JDK and a JRE. Further, the `JAVA_HOME` variable is entirely irrelevant. Nothing in the JDK or JRE uses that variable. What matters, is your `PATH` variable or in other words, which actual `java.exe` file will be used when you type `java` without a prepended path.

Comment: You named three locations, but when you type `java` on the command line, only one can be loaded. The first in your list is a launcher that will use the Windows Registry to find the installation to use. You can use the Java Control Panel to change that setting. But that’s riding a dead horse. The versions after Java 8 don’t use this stuff anymore. The best you can do, is to uninstall the JRE. This should also remove the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe` launcher. Then, typing `java` should find the binaries according to the `PATH` you’ve posted and work fine.

Comment: Cool. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if this can be of help https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html
Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error  jvm.dll should be found  in JAVA_HOME/bin/server folder . check whether  JAVA_HOME is set correctly (JAVA_HOME: D:\config\jdk). If not path for  JAVA_HOME should be corrected by changing in  environment variables.
Otherwise check whether the path bin/server exists inside the JAVA_HOME folder & installation is  fine.

Comment: I have to say I‘ve checked all env variables and tried to reboot. As I showed in the question, my JAVA_HOME setting do point to the jdk address. But strangely the instruction returned an error from javaSE folder.

Comment: Java doesn’t care for `JAVA_HOME` at all.